# HP Bios update filled recovery partition in windows 7 on HP Pavilion g6

Tags: bios, hp-pavilion, partition-recovery

I recently purchased an HP Pavilion g6.  I received a message that the BIOS should be updated.  I said OK and now the partition for recovery data is filled and I continually have a message to that effect flashing on the screen. How do I clear space in the partition or make it larger?  It is the E partition on my computer.

Comment: Just disable the message. The recovery partition is never modified, so there's no reason you'd want any empty space there. (Or better yet, go into the disk manager and unmount it. You don't ever need to access it while Windows is running.)

Comment: Just checking - I've seen a lot of people set Windows Backup to store the backups on the recovery partition. If you have, turn it off and if you feel comfortable, delete the files Windows Backup created.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "You don't ever need to access it while Windows is running" actually HP recovery manager does if used to start HP restore  while in Windows.

Comment: @Moab: It should mount it itself then.

Answer (score 0):

I think E is HP_TOOLS partition, double check that.

Ignore this warning for now, bios update stores the old bios files that were replaced on the HP_TOOLS partition, in case the bios becomes corrupted it can be rolled back to a previous version, a critical and needed feature.

DO Not try to modify the partitions, be warned.

I have posted a bug report with HP about this, I will edit this post if I get feedback.

If it is the Recovery Partition, use [Windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) to see what is on Recovery drive E, if you see a folder named as your User name, then you have Windows System Restore turned on for E, it needs to be turned off. Once Windirstat runs (may take a while), expand the E drive to see folders on E.